# How trigger an event after insert an event into input jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code: 
`$("#zipCodeInputEl").val("84604");` after I insert the value `84604` press the submit button but I have an error because it does not validate my value. But if I delete a number of the inserted value and insert it from the keyboard, it validates my value.

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="welcome-scene__foreground"> 
  <form _ngcontent-c3="" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched"> 
    <label _ngcontent-c3="" class="label" for="zipCodeInputEl">ZIP Code</label> 
    <input _ngcontent-c3="" numericvalidator="true" class="input input--inverse ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="zipCodeInputEl" maxlength="5" name="zipCodeInputEl" required="" type="text"> 
    <button _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn--welcome btn--stretched" id="btnStart" preventdoublesubmit="">Get Started</button> 
  </form>
</div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zipCodeInputEl").val("84604");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btnStart").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: what is the type of the input?

Comment: The type is text, but validation is done to enter only numbers

Comment: add to the question the validate function

Comment: It is not related to the validation function. If I enter the numbers by typing them all is ok, but I want to go by inserting them by code.

Comment: then what is this error that you got

Comment: The error is that when I click on the button I specify that I did not enter the value in the input. Although the visual value is there.

Comment: can you post the relevant code

Comment: This is the code: `<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="welcome-scene__foreground"> 
 <form _ngcontent-c3="" novalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched"> 
  <label _ngcontent-c3="" class="label" for="zipCodeInputEl">
   ZIP Code
  </label> 
  <input _ngcontent-c3="" numericvalidator="true" class="input input--inverse ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" id="zipCodeInputEl" maxlength="5" name="zipCodeInputEl" required="" type="text"> 
  <button _ngcontent-c3="" class="btn btn--welcome btn--stretched" id="btnStart" preventdoublesubmit="">
   Get Started
  </button> 
 </form>
</div>`

Comment: when I said "post the relevant code" I meant to edit your question and add the code to it, also I want to see the js code too, html alone doesn't have meaning

Comment: For input: 
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#zipCodeInputEl").val("84604");
});`
For button:
`$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#btnStart").trigger("click");
});`

Comment: @LauraCirstea Edit you question and add your corresponding html and jquery code.

Comment: @LauraCirstea are you listening to the change of the input like this `$("#zipCodeInputEl").on('change', your_validation_function)`

Comment: You should a the relevant Angulr tag to your question (There's 4... Add the right one. Angular, AngularJs, Angular2 or Angular4)

Answer (score 3):

> if I delete a number of the inserted value and insert it from the keyboard, it validates my value.

So the trick would be to trigger an `input` event on the input element to simulate a user action...
Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#zipCodeInputEl").val("84604").trigger("input");

  $("#btnStart").trigger("click");
});
```

Comment: I tried, but it does not work, it does not insert the value.

Comment: Okay... Then try with `.trigger("keyup")`.

Comment: Inserts the value, but when it clicks the button, it specifies that the value was not entered.

Comment: I just noticed `_ngcontent-c3`... If you use Angular, you should look for an Angular solution. I think that's the issue here. I'm not familiar with Angular though.